# ModuleNotFoundErrorが発生する

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratory を使用しています。

`pip install pylinac` でインストールし、以下のデモを走らせたところ、エラーが発生しました。

**デモのコード:**

```
from pylinac import Starshot

Starshot.run_demo()
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ede644869295> in <module>
----> 1 from pylinac import Starshot
      2 
      3 Starshot.run_demo()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pylinac/ct.py in CatPhanBase()
   2041             )
   2042 
-> 2043     def results(self, as_list: bool = False) -> Union[str, list[list[str]]]:
   2044         """Return the results of the analysis as a string. Use with print().
   2045 

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

調べたところ、pythonのversionは3.9から動作するようなので、

What’s New In Python 3.9 — Python 3.11.1 documentation
[pylinacのサイト](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections)

以下の手順で update したところ、ModuleNotFoundError が表示されます。確認するとpylinacはインストールしているようなので困っています。どなたか解決方法をご教授いただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
!wget -O mini.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x mini.sh
!bash ./mini.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y jupyter
!conda install -q -y google-colab -c conda-forge
!python -m ipykernel install --name "py39" --user
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ede644869295> in <module>
----> 1 from pylinac import Starshot
      2 
      3 Starshot.run_demo()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylinac'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Pythonを3.9にするのはこちらの記事が詳しそうですが。[Google Colaboratory で Python3.9 を実行する](https://zenn.dev/ganariya/articles/google-colaboratory-python39) あるいは質問内容からするとこちらを参考にされているのでしょうか。[Colab Python 3.9 Update.ipynb - Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1m47aWKayWTwqJG--x94zJMXolCEcfyPS?usp=sharing) Minicondaのインストーラパッケージも版数が新しくなっているようですが。[Miniconda3 - Anaconda repo](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。教えていただいたサイトのコードを入力してみたのですが、2.7.17と表示されます。コピーし使用するだけではだめなのでしょうか？

Comment: それだとどうもPythonの版数が3.x系ではなく2.7.17に変わってしまったのでは？ もしかしたらこちらの記事が参考になるかも。[How to Change Python Version in Google Colab : 3 Steps Only](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/change-python-version-in-google-colab-steps/) 少なくともどの版数の環境があるのかは`!sudo update-alternatives --config python3`で分ると思われます。

Comment: pythonのVersionは3.9に変更できましたがやはり同様のエラーが発生します。
やはり原因は別のところにあるのでしょうか。。

Comment: 変更後の環境に実際に pylinac があるのかどうか、`!pip show pylinac`などで確かめてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 確認するとやはり
`Name: pylinac
Version: 3.6.3
Summary: A toolkit for performing TG-142 QA-related tasks on a linear accelerator
Home-page: https://github.com/jrkerns/pylinac
Author: James Kerns
Author-email: jkerns100@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: Pillow, pydicom, reportlab, scipy, argue, matplotlib, tqdm, numpy, py-linq, scikit-image, cached-property
Required-by:`　と表示されるので問題なくインストールできていそうです。。。

Comment: そうなると、もっと詳しい人でないと分からなそうですね。